# Branding Intranet Site with Fabric UI

Tags: sharepoint, sass

We are in the process of implementing a new company intranet site which has been running and it will continue on Sharepoint 2016.

We have looked at Fabric UI as the underline framework for implementing it but honestly we have no experience in customizing it and make the site look as our company marketing department asked us.

Does anyone can point us to a place where we can get documentation of the SASS provided as part of the Fabric UI Core?

Thanks,
Michel Fornaris

Answer (score 0):

Here are some good documentation and example about branding SharePoint site with Office Fabric UI:

[Get started with Fabric JS](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/GetStarted/GetStarted.html)

[SharePoint Framework Tutorial 6 - Using Office UI Fabric Components](https://channel9.msdn.com/blogs/OfficeDevPnP/SharePoint-Framework-Tutorial-6-Using-Office-UI-Fabric-Components)